# Console command recAudio is broken in modern iOS

Tags: ios, audio, jailbreak, cydia, binary

A while ago I used to use the recaudio console application provided by Erica Utilities, installed in Cydia on jailbroken devices. It doesn't seem to work any longer, which isn't terribly surprising, since it was built in 2008.

When I run `./recAudio`, I get:

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

I had read that this was due to the binary being compiled for an older processor, and some people had recommended running:

```
sed -i'' 's/\x00\x30\x93\xe4/\x00\x30\x93\xe5/g;s/\x00\x30\xd3\xe4/\x00\x30\xd3\xe5/g;' recAudio
```

And while this helps, now I am getting:

```
Start talking. Press ^C to finish.
Starting recording
Could not start Audio Queue
```

At which point I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work, and I have to kill the process to get out. I am left with a 4096 byte empty AIFF file.

Has anyone had any luck getting this to work on more modern processors and devices? The project seems abandoned and I haven't found any sources for me to try to recompile.